# gcloud SSH failure

Tags: ssh, gcloud

When trying to SSH to a gcloud vm i get the error
permission denied (publickey)
Key_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

My pub key is correct in the metadata and I have sufficient permissions to connect.
I can connect to every other vm in the project.
It is in my known hosts
It is accessing the correct file for the key exchange
it was created in 2015 and the browser terminal does not not work for anyone, including the only person who can ssh into it. the google provided terminal is also unable to connect. there is no password required and when connecting with the gcloud compute ssh command it asks for a password evetime even though they were disabled.
firewall rules are configured to allow the desired port and my ip is not blocked.
I am using a debian linux distro
does anyone know where the issue is causing it to block connections from the google shell and users with keys.

Comment: there is also a return code [255] that comes in the error

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt update

sudo apt install google-compute-engine google-compute-engine-oslogin 
google-guest-agent google-osconfig-agent

running this on the problem server resolved the issue, older servers do not have these packages by default.
on the user machine the user will need to run:

ssh-keygen -f "/home/[user]/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts" -R "compute.[GuestIdNumber]"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).